# difference between variable-status when opening a file

Tags: fortran

What is the difference between this two IOSTAT variable-status:

```
open(...., IOSTAT=openstatus)
open(...., IOSTAT=IOCHK)
```

Are they just two parameter that should give or get some result or the word `iostat` is a Fortran key to compile and has difference with `openstatus` or the other word?

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/510888

Answer (score 0):

`openstatus` and `IOCHK` are just to different integer variables. You can name them as you wish, it doesn't matter. The behavior is the same. If an error or end condition happens, the variable is set to some non-zero value.